# How can infinitives, participles, gerunds.. act?

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, participles

I've seen infinitives function in a few different ways.

But in which ways can they function? I've seen infinitives function as direct objects, subjects, and a couple other ways, but how else can they act?

Some example sentences that I'm not sure how they're functioning:

"I don't know where to go"
"The books to return are right here"
"Emergency Room physicians struggle to prevent their own depression and burnout."

P.S I've heard infinitives for example act like complements and also modifiers, but what does this mean? (an example sentence would help)

And as a separate question:
I was confused in these sentences how the subordinate clauses are functioning, although they aren't infinitivial

They have tons of speed and talent around him that can help him make big plays.

It’s so heavy that you can’t pick it up

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Could you possibly explain your question a little more clearly? For example, do you mean to ask this: "As what parts of speech do infinitives, gerunds, etc., function?" It would also be helpful if you would give examples of the cases that you're having trouble understanding.

Comment: I made it a bit more specific. Yes, I am trying to find out how infinitives function.

Comment: Infinitivals have a wide range of functions, but not direct object (only NPs can be objects). Their main functions are subject, complement of a verb noun or adjective, adjunct, modifier of a noun. In your examples, "where to go" is an interrogative complement of "know"; "to return" modifies "books"; "to prevent their own depression and burnout" is complement of "struggle",

Comment: Thanks BillJ. You said infinitives cannot act as direct objects. Why are they called complements rather than direct objects, like in this case - "I wanted to leave." If you said "I wanted a bunny" would this be a direct object, though?

Comment: Also, for the clause "that can help him make big plays", is it a complement or something or does it function in a specific way in the sentence?

Comment: @BillJ One more thing. Do you happen to know any grammar books or websites that teach what you're saying? I would like to be able to study and do some research to clear up more things.

Comment: I've just spotted a typo in one of my earlier comments, so I am re-posting it here: "In your last two examples, "that can help him make big plays" is a relative clause modifying "tons of speed and talent", within which is the infinitival clause "make big plays" functioning as complement of "help". Finally, "that you can’t pick it up" is a declarative content clause functioning as a complement in clause structure.

Comment: Direct objects are a sub-type of complement. Yes, the NP "a bunny" is object of "wanted", but NPs have a different structure and distribution to that of clauses: they can function as objects, but clauses can't. My re-posted comment answers your question about the clause "that can help him make big plays". I can thoroughly recommend A Student's Introduction to English Grammar, by Huddleston & Pullum. [link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Students-Introduction-English-Grammar/dp/0521612888)

Comment: Thanks BillJ, It helps a lot! I will most certainly look into it.

Comment: I happened to come up with another example with an infinitive. It's "he wants everyone to have fun." Would "to have fun" be a complement of "wants," (indirect object "everyone") or would it be something else? Would this "complement" also be of a verb? I was a little confused because he doesn't want to have fun, but instead he wants "everyone" to have fun.

Comment: The infinitival clause "to have fun" is complement of "wants". "Everyone" is the syntactic direct object of "wants", and also the _understood_ (semantic) subject of the infinitival clause. Verbs like "want" are called catenative verbs because they can form a chain, separated only in some instances by a noun, as in your example..

Comment: @BillJ Going back to this relatively old discussion, I'm still a bit confused about "It's so heavy that you can't pick it up." I am confused on the structure and breakdown of the sentence. Why is "that you can't pick it up" a content clause? I'm not sure what "complement in clause structure" means, either. Is there any extraposition going on or no? I originally thought "that you can't pick it up" was a subject, but is "it" the subject? I'm just quite confused on the sentence. I don't even know how "so heavy" is functioning.

Comment: If you said something like "I hate the fact that he never calls me," is "that he never calls me a content clause too." The thing is though in this one you can say "I hate that he never calls me," and leave out the NP. This is technically a different structure too. I am also confused on this one, though. Is there a complement or object of "hate," and what is it? I'm confused on if "fact" is object or the clause is, if it's even an object.

Comment: You've asked too many questions for comments, so I've put up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a definition: There are three kinds of finite subordinate clause: relative, comparative and content. The latter lacks the special properties of the other two, and is regarded as the default kind. The term 'content clause' reflects its default status: it suggests that the clause is simply selected for its semantic content.

“That you can’t pick it up” is clearly not a relative or comparative clause, so it can only be a content clause. In the sentence “It’s [so heavy that you can’t pick it up]”, the content clause “that you can’t pick it up” is a complement because it has to be licensed (specifically permitted or required) by the “so” that modifies “heavy”. We know that because if we drop “so”, the bracketed AdjP becomes ungrammatical. The AdjP “so heavy that you can’t pick it up” is subjective complement of “was” – a complement because it is an obligatory item. The content clause is complement of “heavy”

We know it’s not an extraposition construction because “it” is referential – it refers to something mentioned earlier in the discourse, whereas extrapositional “it” is just a dummy subject.

Yes, “the fact that he never calls me” is a content clause functioning as complement of “fact”. “I hate that he never calls me” is OK in AmE but rarely heard in BrE. The content clause is complement of the verb “hate”. It’s important to remember that clauses can never be objects – only NPs can.

Comment: Thanks a lot BillJ! I've been reading "A student's introduction to english grammar," and it's been very useful. I haven't gotten to far into it, so I have a question I've not yet discovered about non finite clauses. In the sentence "To be wise is to have patience" (random example I came up with), is there an overt subject in the infinitivial clause? (both of them) I'm sure it says it in the book, but it would be nice to have a further explanation. (Usually there's a subject easier to find, as in "Preparing breakfast, the man flipped pancakes.")

Comment: That is one of the only questions I still have: what is the subject in an infinitivial clause like the one above? I really appreciate taking your time to answer my questions by the way.

Comment: No, there's no overt subject. The meaning depends on inference, in this case something like 'people in general'.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a little confused on this: What kind of finite clause is it if the head is "while?" Let's say in this sentence, "I ate while mowing the lawn." I'm not sure which kind of category "while" would fall into. I'm not sure if this example "I ate as I mowed the lawn" also falls into the same category.

Comment: Traditional grammar treats “while” and “as” in your examples as subordinating conjunctions, and thus “while mowing the lawn” and “as I mowed the lawn” as subordinate clauses. They are clearly not relative or comparative clauses, so they must be content clauses.  The clauses function as adjuncts of time. Modern grammar looks at things a slightly different way, but I won’t confuse you with that. You’ll discover the difference as you work your way through SIEG.

Comment: Thanks BillJ, that's really interesting. Are the "while" and "as" in the sentences functioning or doing anthing in particular? Or are they just randomly there in the sentence, just being a content clause? (I'm not completely sure what you mean by 'adjunct': I haven't gotten too far into modern grammar yet)

Comment: I also have a question relating to this. In the sentence, "Just because you delete something doesn’t mean it’s gone," is the content clause (trad grammar subordinate clause) functioning as a subject or an adjunct of time? Like my previous question, I'm not completely sure what an adjunct of time does, functions, or even means,

Comment: Is it true "because you delete something doesn't mean it's gone" is functioning as a subject? I feel like this is the right conclusion. So wouldn't the sentence would be "Just because you delete something (S) does (not) mean (VP) it's gone (complement)